# xset dpms force on no longer working after update

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, suspend, power-management

I have an application that is supposed to sleep/wake the display on my XUbuntu box by using the following commands:

To sleep:

```
xset dpms force off
xset dpms 0 0 60
```

And then to wake (and keep awake):

```
xset dpms force on
xset dpms 0 0 0
```

This was working properly right up until I upgraded to 20.04.1 yesterday. Now the sleep command still works, and wake turns the monitor on, but I'm just left with a blank screen - to get it to really wake up, I have to move the mouse.

At first after the update it looked like a problem with the screen saver somehow getting activated and locking the screen, but I have since turned the screen saver off completely (not sure how it got turned on), and still am stuck with a blank screen on "wake". How can I get the wake command working again?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got same issue.

Comment: @ubuntuUssser Not really, no. I managed to work around the issue by adding commands to my program (written in C++/Qt) to move the mouse and type the space bar, but that's not really a command-line type option.

Comment: I also have this error: 20.10 -> 21.04 but screen doesn't go off it keeps on