# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop Screen off

Tags: 18.04, power-management, screen, kiosk

I've got a computer with Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop configured with no screen saver and not switch off screen after N minutes, and works fine since the screen is always on.

Now, I want to run an application in 'kiosk mode' i.e, I want to run in maximized size and without the desktop interface.

I have configured an user without password and I've added to its .profile a last line that launches my app:

```
./my-app.sh
```

This works because It seems that the whole systems waits for my app to finish before loading the desktop itself (I don't know if there is a better solution for this, maybe for another question).

Anyway, this works but after 10 minutes the screens are switched off until a key is pressed or mouse moved.

Is there a parameter anywhere to prevent this happens?

Comment: Could you check answers here https://askubuntu.com/q/696738/26246 , It could be Energy Star feature of the physical monitor.

Comment: Seems to be correct but... i have to execute xset -dpms periodically in order to work in my setup

Comment: So may be even `xset dpms force on` may be related to https://askubuntu.com/q/1281699/26246 . I am expect `xset -dpms` to work till monitor is restarted. Currently thinking, it could be activated/controlled by another running service that interfere.